# Parsing html with lxml in python

Tags: python, lxml

I have the following html code:

```
...
<p class="footer">[[footer]] - <a href="/rss">feed</a> if you want.</p>
...
```

I am trying to extract "[[footer]] - [feed](/rss) if you want." from this code including the spaces (general task in to find all strings on page containing text "[[footer]]").

```
import lxml.etree as ET
html = """
<p class="footer">[[footer]] - <a href="/rss">feed</a> if you want.</p>
"""

elem = ET.fromstring(html)

infos = elem.xpath('/p')
for info in infos:
    print 1, info.text
print 2, ET.tostring(elem) #
```

**Results:**

```
1, [[footer]] -
2, <p class="footer">[[footer]] - <a href="/rss">feed</a> if you want.</p>
```

**Desired result**

```
[[footer]] - <a href="/rss">feed</a> if you want.
```

**Question**

It is humbling that I have to ask this question, since it doesn't seem like it should be hard.

How can I extract all strings on page containing text "[[footer]] using lxml?

Comment: Since I am not sure of the exact code I will just comment that I think what you want is use is ET.tostring(info) text refers to the text of an element which in your case is the stuff between the ><

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the exact string, since lxml converts the HTML to it's own internal data structure, and then you'll want to use the tostring() method to convert it back to a string (meaning that attributes, nesting, etc, could come out in a slightly different order/format, and whitespace will not be preserved).  An example of this would be something like:

```
for info in infos:
    #Check for some string in the displayed text
    if "search string" in info.text:
        print ET.tostring(info)
```

Since it sounds like you mentioned this could be anywhere on the page, you'll likely want to make this check info a function and call it recursively as you walk all the elements . . .

Edit in response to your comment:

You could do something like this:

```
for info in infos:
    #Check for some string in the displayed text
    if "search string" in info.text:
        output_str = info.text
        for children in info:
            output_str += ET.tostring(children)
        print output_str
```

Comment: ET.tostring(info) gives `<p class="footer">[[footer]] - <a href="/rss">feed</a> if you want.</p>` - but is it possible to get it without found tags (without <p class="footer"> )?